# Use the return value of response->json response in the backend

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel 8 and I am working on an existing project.
There is a function that returns a json response :

```
    public function ReturnTest($num) {
        return response()->json(array('test done succesfully',$num),200);
    }
```

and I want to use that returned array in the backend in this function :

```
    public function ViewPage() {
       /* $data = DB::select('select * from domaines');
        dd($data);*/
        $var=$this->ReturnTest(25);
        dd($var);

    }
```

```
this is the result : 
Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse {#290 ▼
  #data: "["test done succesfully",25]"
  #callback: null
  #encodingOptions: 0
  +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag {#291 ▶}
  #content: "["test done succesfully",25]"
  #version: "1.0"
  #statusCode: 200
  #statusText: "OK"
  #charset: null
  +original: array:2 [▶]
  +exception: null
}
```

Comment: This is a design problem. In other words, I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem. Move the logic from `ReturnTest` into a separate function that just returns the data; then in your controller return it as JSON, and in your other function use it as the raw data.

Comment: you could call `getData` on the Response to get the `json_decode`d data from it

Comment: @lagbox you *could*, but don't you think needing to do so is indicative of a design flaw?

Comment: @BrianThompson sure but that isn't what is being asked ... you can nudge someone in the correct direction but ultimately we answer their questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really had to do things this way you could call `getData` on the Response to get the decoded (`json_decode`) version of the data:

```
$var->getData();
```

Comment: Thank you so much That's exactly what i needed

Answer (score -1):

Why you don't just return your response without wrapping it up?

```
public function ReturnTest($num) {
    return array('test done succesfully',$num);
}
```